# Create line breaks from text field

Tags: templating

I'm looking for a way to output line break from a text field.

I'm aware of the "Allow line breaks" option and I have set that to true. I've then entered text with multiple new lines. However, when this text gets output in the template, there are no line breaks.

I have tried using [Twig's new line to br function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/nl2br.html), like this:

```
{% set address = contact.address|nl2br %}
```

but this creates `<br />` tags in the text, not the markup - that is, you can actually see the `<br />` in the browser and no actual line breaks are being created.

Am I doing something wrong here? Are there any alternative solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Expanding from [Pascal Mollet](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/users/149/pascal-mollet)'s answer, this was the solution I came up with.

First setting the address variable with the `|nl2br` filter:

```
{% set address = contact.address|nl2br %}
```

Then, outputting that variable with the `|raw` filter:

```
{{address|raw}}
```

Using them both together at once like this (as Pascal suggested):

```
{% set address = contact.address|nl2br|raw %}
```

didn't work.

Comment: I was able to use @Pascal's suggestion successfully - though instead of setting the variable, I just printed out the code like so: `{{ contact.address|nl2br|raw }}`

Answer (score 11):

You could also add the Twig [`raw`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html) filter, which should prevent the automated escaping.

```
{% set address = contact.address|nl2br|raw %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and this is what I ended up doing with a small difference because using `|nl2br` and `|raw` together didn't work. A bit strange though that the `|nl2br` filter would encode the `<br />`'s...

Comment: found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Just using `|nl2br` inside a `<p>` tag (or whatever you choose) worked for me.

`<p>{{ contact.address|nl2br }}</p>`

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Craft v3.1, I noticed that none of the answers worked for me.

I only got it to work by placing `raw` before `nl2br`.

This is what worked for me: `{{ entry.customFieldName |raw|nl2br }}`

Answer (score 1):

Add raw before nl2br

```
{% set address = contact.address|raw|nl2br %}
```

This will work.