# How to create single lines from a plain text field with line breaks

Tags: templating, plaintext

Building on this question here: [Create line breaks from text field](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2830/create-line-breaks-from-text-field/2834)

What approach would be best for breaking a multi line plain text field into multiple single lines to be used as:

```
<span>{{ textfield.lineOne }}</span>
<span>{{ textfield.lineTwo }}</span>
<span>{{ textfield.lineThree }}</span>
```

At the moment, my approach is to use a Matrix for the user to be able to add individual lines, but I'd much rather I was able to present the client with a multiline text field and rework them in the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{% set text %}
    Here is some
    Text that spans
    multiple lines
{% endset %}

{% set textArray = text | split('\n') | filter %}

{% for line in textArray %}
    <span>{{ line }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Exactlay what I needed! Cheers, Trevor. 

Answer (score 2):

I've made a little macro for this:

```
{% macro splitText(text) %}
  {% set text = text|nl2br|raw %}
  {% set text = '<span class="split_text">' ~ text|replace('<br />', '</span> <span class="split_text">') ~ '</span>' %}
  {{ text|raw }}
{% endmacro %}
```

You may need to tweak it a bit, but this is what worked for me.

Comment: Perfectly good answer. Ended up going with Trevor's below because I liked the control of the forloop. Gave me access to 'loop.index' in there, too. Thanks though, Will!

Comment: Makes sense to me. I like that solution better, too :)